# CURL work on localhost not on server

Tags: php, curl, localhost

i am totaly new to CURL thing . i have a problem .

i have the below script which supposed to get remote files using a proxy , i am trying this code on my local host machine and it is working great "done successfully part: .

when i run it from server , it just keep going to the "invalid proxy" although it is same proxy as used in the local host ..

```
<?php
$dots = '';
include($dots.'classes/config.php');
$wordsLimitPerCall = 1;
$maxAttemptsTrials = 3;
$timeout = 10; // Seconds


$proxy = sqlSelectRow('proxy', array(
    'condition'=>'not_valid=0',
    'order'=>'rand()'
));
echo '<ul>';
if($proxy)
    echo '<li>Using proxy: '.$proxy['proxy'].':'.$proxy['port'].'</li>';
$wordsRes = sqlSelectRows('words', array(
    'condition'=>'is_done=0 and trials<'.$maxAttemptsTrials,
    'limit'=>$wordsLimitPerCall,
    'order'=>'created asc'
));
while($arr = $wordsRes->fetch_assoc()) {

    $word = urlencode($arr['word']);

    $url = 'http://example.com'.$word;
    $callSettings  = array(
        'method'=>'curl', 
        'timeout'=>$timeout
    );
    if($proxy)
        $callSettings['proxy'] = $proxy['proxy'].':'.$proxy['port'];
    $result = callRemoteURL($url, $callSettings);
    $filename = urldecode($word);

    $filename = 'file/'.$arr['id'].' - '.$filename.'.mp3';
    echo '<li>Getting the word: '.$word.'</li>';
    if($result && strpos($result, '<html')===false) {
        if(file_exists($dots.$filename))
            unlink($dots.$filename);
        fileWrite($filename, $result);
        $is_done = 1;
        echo '<li>done successfully</li>';
    }
    else {
        $is_done = 0;
        if($proxy) {
            sqlUpdate('proxy', array(
                'not_valid'=>0
            ), array(
                'condition'=>'id='.$proxy['id']
            ));
            echo '<li>Proxy is not valid</li>';

        }
    }
    sqlUpdate('words', array(
        'trials'=>$arr['trials']+1,
        'path'=>$url,
        'last_call_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'is_done'=>$is_done
    ), array(
        'condition'=>'id='.$arr['id']
    ));

}
echo '</ul>'; ?>
```

below the function called from utils

```
<? php 


                if($set['method']=='curl' && extension_loaded('curl'))
                        {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $set['timeout']); // Seconds
                            if($set['proxy'])
                                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $set['proxy']);
                            ob_start();
                            if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
                            {
                                $errorNo = curl_errno($ch);
                                if($errorNo==28)
                                    print_r('The connection took time more than '. $set['timeout'].' seconds, so we disconnected the process');
                                else
                                if($errorNo!=7)
                                    print_r(curl_error($ch));
                                $result=false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $result = ob_get_contents();
                            }
                            ob_end_clean();
                            return $result;
                        }
        ?>
```

sorry if its too long ... but i've spent the last couple days tryng to find out . any idea or what shall i do ?

Comment: for localhost you do not required proxy settings.please check your proxy settings

Comment: the fact is it is working on localhost , my problem is when i upload it to the server